# php turn line break into semicolon

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file with this:

```
software
hardware
educational
games
languages
.
.
.
```

I need a new csv file with:

```
software;hardware;educational;games;languages;....
```

How can I do that?

I'm doing:

```
<?php
$one = file_get_contents('one.csv');

$patterns =" /\\n/";

$replacements = ";";

$newone = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $one);
echo $newone;

file_put_contents('newone.csv', $newone );
?>
```

This adds the semicolon at the end of the line but the line break is still there

Comment: I wouldn't write code to do this unless it needs to be automated. Any decent text editor can do the trick if you only need it once.

Comment: even if he doesn't really need it, this is a good training and he'll be happy to know how to do when he needs to automate it :))

Comment: Needs to be automated :( Please see the post again I was able to get rid off the quotes. Thanks

Comment: you probably have a cr at the end of the line too .. match on `"\\n\\r"` (notice I left out the space you had)

Comment: Please note the OP edited the question and removed the quotes in the input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly none of you mentioned `file()` that returns what he needs:

```
$cont = file('somefile.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
file_put_contents('somefile.csv',implode(';',$cont));
```

2 lines of code without using slow regex

## OR

if you need less code, here with 1 line of code, the way i like !

```
file_put_contents(
  'somefile.csv',
   implode(
      ';',
      file('somefile.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)
   )
);
```

Comment: Amazing, with just two lines! Thanks a ton!!

Comment: :) If you need to be more compact.. you can compress it with only 1 line... see edit

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do this.
  Edit : tested this, works correct.

```
 <?php
    $row = 1;
    $readHandle = fopen("in.csv", "r"); // open the csv file
    $writeHandle = fopen("out.csv","w");
    $subArr = array();
    while (($data = fgetcsv($readHandle, 1000, "\n")) !== FALSE) {
             $myStr = $data[0]; // this stores the zeroth column of each CSV row
             $subArr[] = $myStr;   // subArr contains all your words      
    }

    fputcsv($writeHandle,$subArr,";"); // it creates a CSV with single line seperated by ;
    fclose($readHandle);
    fclose($writeHandle);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could get a `preg_match_all()` to get every alphanumeric word surrounded by quotes into an array.

Then you just loop on that array and display them adding a semicolon.

Comment: Please see the post again I was able to get rid off the quotes.. but I'm really bad at regular expressions :( Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as a one off, I would run home to mama...

```
perl -p -i -e 's|(.*)\n|$1;|m' one.cvs
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file may have carriage returns. Try this:

```
$newone = str_replace("\r\n", ';', $one);
```

Answer (score 0):

To cover all possibilities:

```
<?php

$file = 'data.csv';

file_put_contents($file, '"software"
"hardware"
"educational"
"games"
"languages"
');

$input_lines = file($file);

$output_columns = array();
foreach($input_lines as $line){
    $line = trim($line); // Remove trailing new line
    $line = substr($line, 1); // Remove leading quote
    $line = substr($line, 0, -1); // Remove trailing quote
    $output_columns[] = $line;
}

echo implode(';', $output_columns);
```

Beware: this code assumes no errors in input file. Always add some validation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing it like this:

```
<?php
$one = file_get_contents('one.csv');

$patterns ="/\\r?\\n/";

$replacements = ";";

$newone = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $one);
echo $newone;

file_put_contents('newone.csv', $newone );
?
```